# JMeter: Server Agent is getting stopped as soon as I am running the Jmeter script and the perfmon i m not bel to see the graph

Tags: performance, jmeter

I am working on JMeter (version 5.2.1) and my requirement is to monitor the server health. Now for that I am using Perfmon plugins (jpgc-perfmon-2.1) and listener to catch the desired output. Also I have downloaded Server Agent (Server Agent-2.2.1 and Server Agent-2.2.3). I am hosting the script and running the server agent on the same machine. Now for capturing the CPU utilization or Memory utilization first I am starting the server Agent and then I am running my JMeter script. But as I am clicking on the start button, the server agent is getting stopped automatically. Also I have tried communication between my local machine and server agent using telnet and its responding properly.

The Error Message I am getting in the JMeter console is:

t java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:138) ~[?:?]
at kg.apc.perfmon.client.StreamTransport.writeln(StreamTransport.java:50) ~[perfmon-2.2.2.jar:?]
at kg.apc.perfmon.client.AbstractTransport.disconnect(AbstractTransport.java:63) ~[perfmon-2.2.2.jar:?]
at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.NewAgentConnector.disconnect(NewAgentConnector.java:36) ~[jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar:?]
at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector.shutdownConnectors(PerfMonCollector.java:281) ~[jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar:?]
at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector.testEnded(PerfMonCollector.java:149) ~[jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar:?]

Answer (score 0):

Check the log of the [Server Agent](http://jmeterplugins.com/wiki/PerfMonAgent/index.html) (or its console output), it should contain the reason or at least a clue.

If you're running the Server Agent on 64-bit Windows it might be the case you're suffering from [SIGAR bug #136](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar/issues/136)

The solution is to re-compile the `sigar-amd64-winnt.dll` library with 64-bit dependencies and replace the one in the Server Agent distribution with the recompiled one. Once done the issue will go away.

If you trust random people in the Internet you can take a fixed version from [here](https://github.com/cnstar9988/sigar/raw/master/sigar-amd64-winnt.dll)

More infromation: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)